# Adding Form Closing Event In Code To Specific Object Instance?

Tags: c#, events

Pretty simple what I want to do, just want to be able to run some code after a form is closed.

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.Show();
f.formClosing ... <- I just want to run code from this context once this form has been closed
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(f_FormClosed);
    f.Show();
}

void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: How can you do this with VB.NET

Answer (score 11):

You can handle the [Form.FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event.

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(myForm_FormClosing);

void myForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(myForm_FormClosing);

Answer (score 0):

[Form.FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) occurs before the form is closed. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened.

The right event to handle is [Form.FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) :

```
form.FormClosed += 
     new Form.FormClosedEventHandler( Place the name of the handler method here ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern inline:

```
FormClosed += (s, a) => { /* your code here */ };
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I register my FORM exit handler this way (using .NET 4.8)

```
public partial class Form1:Form {
    public Form1() {
        this.FormClosed +=  Form1_Closing;
    }
    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Doing something while exit
    }
}
```