# Form1 execute Method when Form2 is closed doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, frame

I'm currently programming an Application in C# with VS Community 2017 to calculate and organize gas things (for the car, how much liter per 100km etc.).
I have two frames, one to show an overview of all data and one to enter new data. When someone enters new data, I want to refresh at frame1. Therefore I have an method which changes the text of an label with the content from the file which has all data saved in it.
So my problem seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877682/c-sharp-make-form1-do-an-action-after-form2-is-closed) problem, but somehow the text of the label doesn't change. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982418/adding-form-closing-event-in-code-to-specific-object-instance) but also here, the label text won't change. I didn't get any errors so I can't provide this, but I think solution1 didn't work because I don't use simply a Frame I use an instance of another already existing frame.
Here are the most important parts of the code:
Frame1:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TankCheck_PC_Edition
{
    public partial class f_StartTC : Form
    {
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        public f_StartTC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Reload();
        }

        public void Reload()
        {
            path += "DataTC.txt";
            try { lbl_test.Text = File.ReadAllText(path); } catch (Exception ex) { }
        }

        ....

        private void cmd_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Input_TC.f_Input Frame2 = new Input_TC.f_Input();
            Frame2.Closed += delegate
            {
                Reload();
            };
            Frame2.Show();
            Frame2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Frame2_FormClosed);      
        }

        void Frame2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Reload();
        }
    }
}
```

Frame2:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Input_TC
{
    public partial class f_Input : Form
    {
        long Tacho = 0;
        double km=0, price=0, tanked = 0;
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+ "DataTC.txt";

        public f_Input()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmd_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...

            if(!File.Exists(path))
                File.WriteAllText(path, output);
            else
                File.AppendAllText(path, output);

            TankCheck_PC_Edition.f_StartTC Test = new TankCheck_PC_Edition.f_StartTC();

            Test.Reload();

            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

where the "..." are unimportant code was skipped. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why is there `path += "DataTC.txt";` in the reload method? Add a breakpoint in reload and see if it hits on form2 closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your `Reload` method multiple times but the `path` variable is only valid the first time the function is called. Each next time the variable is altered the path is invalid and an exception occurs.

You can fix the problem like this:

```
public void Reload()
{
    var fullPath = path + "DataTC.txt";
    try { lbl_test.Text = File.ReadAllText(fullPath); } catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot that it would add it everytime^^ Thanks for this explicit and fast answer :)